# The built-in Raspberry Pi 4 Wifi doesn't work, but a USB wifi adapter does, is the built-in Wifi broken?

Tags: networking, wifi, usb, pi-4, ethernet

The only WIFI network I'm able to use is 5G WPA EAP.  The Pi 4 it will connect to an access point, but on it's own it doesn't connect to the internet.  When I ping [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) I get `Temporary failure in name resolution`.  When I check status bar on VNC, the Wifi fan symbol just keeps on disconnecting and reconnecting.

Here is the confusing part: If I plug in my Wireless-G USB Adapter though, the Wifi suddenly works just fine.  Strangley, if I also have the ethernet connected, the Wifi slowly but eventually connects after many attempts.

Here is what `iwconfig` shows when the USB Adapter plugged in, `wlan0` looks exactly the same on `iwconfig`, whether or not I have internet access:

```
wlx000e3b09eb71  IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"XXX"
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.447 GHz  Access Point: 07:2F:E1:G8:6E:46
          Bit Rate=54 Mb/s   Tx-Power=13 dBm
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=48/70  Signal level=-62 dBm
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:25   Missed beacon:0

usb0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"XXX"
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.785 GHz  Access Point: A0:15:4A:18:2D:E4
          Bit Rate=12 Mb/s   Tx-Power=31 dBm
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=56/70  Signal level=-54 dBm
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
```

I've tried turning the wlan0 power management on and off, that doesn't help.

Is something wrong with the Pi's built-in wifi?

Additional info as requested:

```
$ ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether gc:b5:31:a4:20:76 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: usb0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 25:63:f3:22:16:8d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.55.0.1/29 brd 10.55.0.7 scope global usb0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: wlx000e3b09eb71: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:2f:2v:47:vs:41 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 17X.XX.XXX.XXX/20 brd 17X.XX.XXX.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlx000e3b09eb71
       valid_lft 73829sec preferred_lft 63029sec
    inet6 be24::2s9f:8615:rs25:1e0g/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether dc:a3:12:b3:99:29 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 16X.XXX.XXX.XXX/16 brd 16X.XXX.255.255 scope global noprefixroute wlan0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::a2f0:dd4d:e5fd:b10e/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

---

```
$ ip route
default via 17X.XX.XXX.X dev wlx000e3b09eb71 proto dhcp src 17X.XX.XXX.XXX metric 304
10.55.0.0/29 dev usb0 proto kernel scope link src 10.55.0.1 linkdown
16X.XXX.X.X/16 dev wlan0 scope link src 169.XXX.XXX.XXX metric 305
17X.XX.XXX.X/20 dev wlx000e3b09eb71 proto dhcp scope link src 17X.XX.XXX.XXX metric 304
```

Comment: `wlx000e3b09eb71` and `wlan0` are connected to different access points with different frequency. Can you please add the contents of `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` and output from `ip addr` and `ip route` to the question?

Answer (score 0):

It seems I had a similar problem with an image that I got pre installed on the SD card. New image created on a PC with Raspberry image writer solved the issue.